# Godot how to get collision layer of colliding objects programmatically?

Tags: game-development, godot, gdscript

I have 3 collision layers:

1. Player
2. Coin
3. Enemy

My nodes are colliding well, but when my Player collides with the Coin or the Enemy i can't differentiate between the two of them. Normally i would do this by setting collision groups but if the layers are already set it may be easier to check the layer.

Posible solution using groups

```
func _on_Player_area_entered(area):
  if area.is_in_group('enemies'):
    pass
  if area.is_in_group('coins'):
    pass
```

How can i get the Coin and the Enemy collision layers programmatically when they collide with Player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to just do what you suggested: Put the coins and enemies in their own Node groups then do `is_in_group` checks in your collision code.

If you want to avoid Node groups, another way of achieving this is creating a separate `Area2D` node in your Player scene that will only collide with coins while the other `Area2D` collides with enemies.